# The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird

I have a project in .Net Framework 4.5 and I had to update to version 4.5.2 and along with that I was forced to update the EF and Firebird libraries.

As shown in the image below, I used EF 5.0 together with Firebird 3.2.

[image]

Upgrade to EF 6.4.4 and Firebird to 7.5.0. The project does not present any compilation error but when executing it, in the EF context file instance I get the following exception:

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=7.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Can someone help me to configure correctly so that Firebird works perfectly with EF 6? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also install [EntityFramework.Firebird](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Firebird/) package and check/modify your config file ([example](https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/docs/entity-framework-6.md)) for new EF6 configuration.